# What purpose does a tail log backup of source db serve to the restore operation using an older backup file?

Tags: sql-server, restore

I have 2 databases: A and B.

I want to replace B with a copy of A. To do that I followed following steps:

1. Backup A
2. Delete B (optional)
3. Restore backup with destination name as B

Step 3 fails because the source db (A) is not in single user mode.

What is the purpose that the restore operation tries to take tail log backup of source database? I know that this activity can be bypassed is options->tail-log backup. But my question is - what purpose does a tail log backup of source db serve to this restore operation?

Step 3 fails because db A (source db) is not in single user mode due to which tail log backup cannot be taken. My question is why does it even bother to take a tail log backup?

Assuming I have a backup file from last month that I want to restore as a new database, then why does it try to take a tail log backup of the source db?

Comment: In what way does Step 3 fail? Can you share the error message, and the SQL Statement you're using for backup? If you're using the SSMS GUI to do the restore, you can use the `Script` button to generate the statements based on the options you select when performing the `RESTORE DATABASE`

Comment: Step 3 fails because db A (source db) is not in single user mode due to which tail log backup cannot be taken. My question is why does it even bother to take a tail log backup?

Comment: It doesn't require a tail log. I'm asking for detail in what you're doing because the results don't make any sense to me.

Answer (score 2):

The purpose of a tail log backup is to ensure that no transactions are written to the database after the backup is taken.

Comment: Ex : If you wanted to migrate the DB "a" from server 1 to server 2 and make sure there will be no data loss in the process, taking a tail of the log of DB "a" on server 1 will make the database "unavailable" to accept any new data, making sure that the restored database on server 2 will be exactly the same as the DB on server 1

Comment: Assuming I have a backup file from 26th June 2022. Suppose I restore it today then why would it try to take a tail log backup?